# Locate Words with Alphabet only in a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This code works when you have a word but if you have many words with white space, then it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Special sign for instance "()/&%¤&)=?=(&%¤##=?`´´&&¤"" is not  alphabet.

The code is below.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The";
    var patt = new RegExp(/^[A-z]+$/);
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: probably (white) spaces.

Comment: Well you are not checking for spaces only A-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for selecting word characters and space-character try:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The world";
    var patt = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z ]+$/); // or \s for all whitespace chars
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

### edit:

to select word-character you should use `\w` or `[A-Za-z]`instead of `[A-z]`,
 because `[A-z]` will also match some non word characters as `"_][`

Comment: The regular expression is also wrong. `[A-z]` will match every character from A to z, this includes characters like `]` and `\`` which are found between Z and a.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly not whitespace

Comment: Yep, that's one problem. But `A-z` is another problem. `A-z` will match `"_][\``, which doesn't contain *any* alphabet characters. It should at least be `[A-Za-z]` instead.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yes I agree. But as far as whitespace is concerned  `' '.charCodeAt()  = 32` ;  while the match `A-z` matches `charCodeAt()` 65 through 122 (which also adds some other characthers as `_][` )

Comment: Yes, and `]` has the character code 93. What I'm saying is that `A-z` will give matches which *aren't* alphabet characters, which is what OP is after.

Comment: I might have note been explicitly with my message! Special sign for instance "()/&%¤&)=?=(&%¤##=?`´´&&¤""34"  is not alphabet.

Comment: Only alphabet [A-Za-z] and white space

Comment: @KLN  I think that `[A-Za-z ]` is what you need , if you also want other [whitespace characters](http://regexone.com/lesson/whitespaces) use `\s` instead of single whitespace